# Cant' Position Caption Div Appropriately

Tags: css

Can you please take a look at [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/sBxP2/1/) and let me know how I can position the div with `.caption` at the bottom of the div with class `.wrapper`.

I already tried to add `position:absolute; bottom:5px;` rules to `.caption` but it positioned the caption div out of the `.wrapper` !

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="caption">Test</div>
 <div class="main"></div>
</div>
```

here is the css rules

```
.wrapper{
height:300px;
width:300px;
background-color:yellow;
}
.main{
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
.caption{
height:10%;
width:100%;
background: rgb(0, 0, 0) ; opacity: 0.7;>
margin-bottom:5px;
color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `position: absolute` should work but you'll need to set `.wrapper` as:

```
.wrapper {
   position: relative;
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/sBxP2/4/

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/shall1987/MwJsG/

CSS

```
.wrapper{
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background-color:yellow;
    position: relative;
}
.main{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;

}
.caption{
    height:10%;
    width:100%;
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0) ; opacity: 0.7;>
    margin-bottom:5px;
    color:white;
    position: absolute;    
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can update your css like this
http://jsfiddle.net/shall1987/MwJsG/

```
.wrapper{
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background-color:yellow;
    position:relative;
}
.main{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;

}
.caption{
    height:10%;
    width:100%;
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0) ; opacity: 0.7;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```